# Displaying outlines for WebGL polygons in Leaflet, source data coming from GeoJSON object

Tags: leaflet, webgl

I have been using the Plugin [Glify](https://github.com/robertleeplummerjr/Leaflet.glify) for Leaflet. It offers a really great and simple way to use web gl to render maps on [Leaflet JS](https://leafletjs.com/). The problem I'm facing is there are custom options for *'vertexShaderSource'* and *'fragmentShaderSource'*, which require complicated shader code. In the long run it's probably fair I learn to write shaders in javascript, C etc., but in the short run this is something I'm very inexperienced in. Is there a way to draw an outline or border to every polygon drawn? I know this has been done in a 3D context and some other languages, however relating that specifically in this context is seeming more difficult.

The relevant code is fairly basic.

```
L.glify.shapes({
    map: map,
    data: geojson,
    color: function(index, point) { 
        //Some code to choose colours 
    },
    opacity: 0.8
});
```

The output is this, which is coloured polygons features, as a layer onto a map.

[image: coloured polygons]

In short, my aim is to render borders around these polygons using some sort of shader.

Comment: Found here : https://github.com/robertleeplummerjr/Leaflet.glify/issues/14 this fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/rdsj64qL/ that could help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a bit of 'cheating' and help of [Turf.js](https://turfjs.org/) library solution is quite simple. Cheating here means that besides original `L.glify.shapes` we add aditional `L.glify.lines` layer where we use the same GeoJSON data as for shapes, but converting them from polygons to lines before passing them to `L.glify.lines`.

So code could look something like this:

```
function polygonsToLines(geojson) {
  var lines = [];
  geojson.features.forEach(function(feature) {
    lines.push(turf.polygonToLine(feature));
  });
  return turf.featureCollection(lines);
}

L.glify.shapes({
  map: map,
  data: geojson,
  color: function(index, point) { 
      //Some code to choose colours 
  },
  opacity: 0.8
});

L.glify.lines({
  map: map,
  latitudeKey: 1,
  longitudeKey: 0,
  data: polygonsToLines(geojson),
  color: function(index, point) { 
      //Some code to choose colours 
  },
  opacity: 1.0
});
```

Comment: Thanks for getting back. Sadly this didn't work. If you run l.glify.lines it shows nothing on the map, and if you run the polygons to line function under l.glify.shapes, it shows randomly selected polygons around the map filled in, with no apparent connection. 
Any idea why this might be?

Comment: Update: running this L.geoJSON(lines).addTo(map); works, meaning the lines are valid! But since it doesn't make use of web gl it defeats the purpose of using this, and runs at around 2-3fps. Issue is likely with glify, can you help?

Comment: I tested this solution on plugin demo example, and it works. You can see it on the following JSFiddle https://jsfiddle.net/TomazicM/dfhvqjmg/1/. This fiddle somehow works only on Firefox. When I run code from my server, it works in all browsers. I suspect it must be something with your GeoJSON that it does now work for you. Dou you get any errors in the console?

Comment: Adding latitudeKey: 1, longitudeKey: 0 made it work for some reason. Thank you very much!

Comment: Good! I'll add those two options to my answer. It looks like those options are needed for GeoJSON lines.

Comment: I had a look at plugin API docs, but `latitudeKey` and `longitudeKey` options are not mentioned there. Then I had a look at the plugin source code. Those two options tell the order of lon and lat coordinates in GeoJSON. Value 0 means corresponding coordinate is in the first place, value 1 means it's in the second place. A bit unusual way of managing that.